# After appending, want to remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have some zoom buttons being added to my Map container

I want to remove these zoom buttons when a particular map image is being used

Code:
JS:

```
Map = function()
{

//private:
var $MapContainer;

this.initMap = function($container, zoomHidden)
{
    $MapContainer = $container;
    $MapContainer.append("<div class='MapImage'></div>");

    if(!zoomHidden)
    {
        $MapContainer.append("<div id='mapZoomIn' class='MapZoomInButton'>+</div>");
        $MapContainer.append("<div id='mapZoomOut' class='MapZoomOutButton'>-</div>");
    }
}

this.setMapProperties = function(mapImage)
{

    $('.MapImage').css('background-image','url("'+mapImage+'")');

    // Where I want to remove the zoom buttons
    if($('.MapImage').css('background-image') === "../images/mapImages/noZooMap.jpg")
    {
        $('.MapZoomInButton').remove();
        $('.MapZoomOutButton').remove();
    }
}
}
```

CSS:

```
.MapImage
{
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
right:0;
background-image: url("../images/mapImages/GenericMapImage.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I'm not sure the proper way to "remove" the Zoom Buttons after I've appended them in a separate method, since the way I show you above is not functioning (the buttons are still present when running the program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method within Map like this and use it when you want to remove the buttons.

```
Map = function() {
  var $MapContainer;

  this.initMap = function($container, zoomHidden) {
    $MapContainer = $container;
    $MapContainer.append("<div class='MapImage'></div>");
    if(!zoomHidden) {
      $MapContainer.append("<div id='mapZoomIn' class='MapZoomInButton'>+</div>");
      $MapContainer.append("<div id='mapZoomOut' class='MapZoomOutButton'>-</div>");
    }
  }

  this.removeZoomButtons = function ($container) {
    $container.remove("#mapZoomIn");
    $container.remove("#mapZoomOut");
  }

  this.setMapProperties = function(mapImage) {
    $('.MapImage').css('background-image','url('+mapImage+')');
    // Where I want to remove the zoom buttons
    if($('.MapImage').css('background-image') === "url(../images/mapImages/noZooMap.jpg)") {
        this.removeZoomButtons($MapContainer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't saying within the if statement `$MapContainer.remove('.MapZoomInButton');
   $MapContainer.remove('.MapZoomOutButton');` simply work too?

Comment: Or even `$MapContainer.remove('#mapZoomIn');
   $MapContainer.remove('#mapZoomOut');` ?

Comment: It would but now your design is more flexible.  You have create a method that can be reused in the Map object as well as outside the map object.

Comment: I see! I tried both ways that I commented here, and your way given in the example, but it still isn't working. It must be something on my end, but you did answer my basic question as to a correct way to go about removing those properties. Thanks!

Comment: check out the if statement.  Verify that the following is correct in your code `if($('.MapImage').css('background-image') === "url(../images/mapImages/noZooMap.jpg)")`..  Perhaps alert out the value of `$('.MapImage').css('background-image')` just prior to the if statment.  We should make sure that the conditional is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Is this line:

```
$('.MapImage').css('background-image','url("mapImage")');
```

exactly what you have in  your code? If so, it's looking for an image at the literal URL "mapImage" rather than at the location specified in the `mapImage` variable.

Changing it to `$('.MapImage').css('background-image','url('+mapImage+')');` should do the trick.

Comment: Whoops, I actually have it like that in the real code, but I've simplified the code to protect company code, and in my edits I put that part wrong. :) I'll edit the example code